# Ranking mysql and query for one people

Tags: php, mysql, database

I use this script for my ranking. But I'm not good in MYSQL so maybe someone can help me to change this script to add to this variable:

```
WHERE id = '$id'
```

This is what i use:

```
    SELECT    id,punkty,
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM      users p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  punkty DESC;
```

I dont know how I can change this script to check one id ? (where id = '$id')

Comment: Can you show us what the database looks like, and what you want your result to be?

Comment: this script show everything from my databse like a ranking but for everyone. I wanna change this to add variable WHERE only

Comment: Add `WHERE id = '$id'` before `ORDER BY`

Comment: not working. always return of this query is 1 not a actual rank for id

Comment: @user3384074 see my answer is that you need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from comments what i understand the rank given by your query against each user,now you want to know the rank for a given user. You can get the desired rank for the given user's id by doing a sub select

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT    id,punkty,
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM      users p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  punkty DESC
  ) t
WHERE id='6';
```

In below demo if you see the second result set,it shows all the users with their rank and the first query is for one user with id = 6 and his rank is 4 according to the result set of second query

### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3988b/6)

Comment: I understand almost everything from this script. Can you give me some link to documentation or some tutorial where i can read what is this single letter: "p" or "r" or "t" ...i searched but i cant find any answer about this

Comment: @user3384074 They are called aliases a short name for a table or column or a subselect more you can read [***MYSQL: ALIASES***](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/alias.php) which will give you a better idea